# Can't get Admob to work

Tags: java, android, admob

```
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

It says cannot resolve symbol AdRequest and cannot resolve Adview. What am I doing wrong? Included the following in my main activity file

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView><com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Also, I've added the following to Build.gradle

```
dependencies {


compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
}
```

I want to display Banner Ads on my app and I'm using Admob for the first time. Added above codes from google dev website. In the app's project structure, I've also enabled Admob.

**EDIT**

I now know what's the problem but cannot fix it. I've enabled Admob from Project Structure and it has added

```
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

in the build.gradle. I've checked a banner example, Example has play-services in external libraries but it doesn't show up in my app.

In my app, play-services only shows up in build.gradle but not in the External Libraries. I only see Android API 23 Platform, < 1.8 >, android-android-23 and support-annotations in my External Libraries column. I tried cleaning the project, rebuilding and also tried Invalidate cache/ Restart. None of them worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add this to the root element of the layout "xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"?

Comment: Yes, I've added -> xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Rebuild your project again.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Same issue again..BTW I don't think I have added the jar. How do I add it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of Android Studio

Comment: You don't need a jar. Gradle dependency should be okay.

Comment: Did you install Google Repository ?

Comment: Yes, I've installed it.

Comment: Try `File -> Invalidate Cache and restart`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in my last project and I solved it like this

Goto `Build` menu

Click on `Clean Project`

let it finish then `Build` menu again and hit `Rebuild Project`

If this didn't solve it.

Try this

you need to edit your manifest file

ad this after `application` tag

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

**EDIT**

Download [this example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/releases/latest) provided by google in their tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) and see if it works or not and let us know what was the result

Comment: I edited my answer download the sample project and test it to see if the problem in your code or from android studio or the SDK.

Comment: I've seen a Banner example project as well. It works but my project doesn't.

Comment: Did you add dependencies to your app level build.gradle or your project level file?

Comment: Added dependencies to the App level build.gradle

Comment: Can you post your MainActivity code relevant to the problem so we can investigate the problem?

Comment: It didn't allow me to add any codes because the imports didn't work

Comment: post it in a comment here and I'll add it to your question if you can't edit it.

Comment: Yes, I've added the AdActivity in the manifest. It shows a red color on AdActivity. By editing, I mean I did not add any codes in the MainActivity because my imports weren't getting accepted.

Comment: If the example works for you make it your project and work on it.